# How to type data top to bottom (Top one should be new post and last one should be oldest one) asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, facebook

I am creating a social network website as facebook, but that website has some errors with posing status , i used following code to post status. I called this method on page_Load event and post button

```
 private DataSet GetData()
{

    string CS=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from PhotoStatusProfile WHERE Email = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() +"'",con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;


    }

}
```

This is html code

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
 <ItemTemplate>

     <div class="yourDivClass" style="border-top: thin none #BBCEB3; border-bottom: thin none #BBCEB3; padding: 10px; height: 121px; width: 548px; margin-top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #e9eaee; border-left-color: #BBCEB3; border-right-color: #BBCEB3;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <div style="width: 58px; height: 62px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/Profile/Image/supun_Profilemini.jpg" Width="55px" />
                        </div>
                    <div style="width: 307px; height: 21px; margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#000066" ><%#Eval("name") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 22px; width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"><%#Eval("Status") %></asp:Label>
                   <br><br>
                         </div>
                    &nbsp;</div>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

post button cs code

```
 protected void Post_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        try
        {



            string inserQuery = "insert into PhotoStatusProfile(Name,Status,Email) values (@Name,@Status,@e)";
            SqlCommand commm = new SqlCommand(inserQuery, conn);
            commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ProfileName.Text);
            commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",TextBox1.Text);
            commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", Label1.Text);



            commm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 


            Label1.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();



        }





        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write("Error -->" + ex.ToString());

             conn.Close();
        }

      //  LoadData();

        Repeater1.DataSource = GetData();
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    TextBox1.Text = "";


}
```

But After i'm posting some status I faced some errors.

1,On this website, [my new post displayed on bottom and oldest one on top](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10846311_1500207470268829_1765213938478321942_n.jpg?oh=abc17a4222bb021e175567c3b3509e6a&oe=550B3A43) but i want new post to top and others Gradually top to bottom ,(descending order by considering time)

2. when i posted big status, [it will display Like this](https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10295033_1500208406935402_8656959474681473990_o.jpg). 
   I want to fix this also. 
   Thanks

Comment: 1) use order by date/datetime desc in your query

Comment: regarding 1: you can add a timestamp to each post and use ORDER BY in your select statement to sort the results.

Comment: could you give me the suitable code?

Comment: 2) using css wrap long word.
 Alternative to Repeater you can use, DataList or ListView

Comment: okay i did it, I want to send time it posted to my database, could you send me any code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about storing some kind of date for each post. Then you can get a sorted list from the database. Something like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from PhotoStatusProfile WHERE Email = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() +" order by CreatedAt desc'",con);
```

This would also allow you to show a "posted"-Date, show posts by day/week/month etc.

Comment: I replace this code for my site, but now not loading data, could you tell me How to get post time and setting this to descending order?

Comment: You need to update your db table and add a new column "CreatedAt" of type "DateTime". Then when saving posts add the time like this: commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedAt", DateTime.Now);

Comment: i got a time to my database but it was not happened that i expected, still order is same, what is the code for ascending order ?

Comment: i did it, but your code should be like this SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from PhotoStatusProfile WHERE Email = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() +"' order by CreatedAt desc",con);

Comment: Sorry i did that from the head :)

Answer (score 0):

[Reversing Repeater order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954797/c-sharp-reverse-repeater-order)

To make a long word wrap  you can apply css:

`word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: break-word is working, can u explain about reversing repeater? the page u gave has not mentioned clearly